# How do I print intermediate data in hadoop map reduce programming framework

Tags: javascript, hadoop, collections, mapreduce

Suppose we have a file contains test::

```
hi how are you 
how is your  job 
how is your family
what is hadoop hi
```

desired output of mapperclass:

```
hadoop[1]

hi[1,1]

how[1,1,1]

is[1,1,1]

your[1,1]
```

something like this for every distinct string....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input file:: 
Dravid Banglore 
Sachin Mumbai 
Dhoni Ranchi 
Dravid Jaipur 
Dhoni Chennai 
Sehwag Delhi 
Gambhir Delhi 
Gambhir Calcutta 
Reducer Output:: Dravid Banglore,Jaipur Dhoni Ranchi,Chennai Gambhir Delhi,Calcutta Sachin Mumbai Sehwag Delhi

This can be achieved using a Map Reduce program.

Mapper Class : Player Name will be key and Place name will be value.

Reducer Class: When we iterate through the key(player name) we get all the values associated with it(place names). We can just construct the string having the key(player name) and comma separated values(place names) and output that from the reducer.

Comment: public void reduce(Text key/*shiv*/, Iterator<LongWritable> value/*[23,56,87,90,778]*/,
     OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter r)throws IOException 
   {
    {
     String s = "";
   while(value.hasNext())
       {
    LongWritable i = value.next();
    s = s+i+",";
       } s=s.substring(0,s.length()-1);
   output.collect(key, new  IntWritable(s));//error 
  }  
}                                                                                                                                can you correct this error?

Comment: s = s+ i+"," ---> this gives you string like this 23,56,87,90,778. Then if we do new Intwritable(23,56,87,90,778) it will throw an error that string cannot be converted to a valid integer. Can you tell your exact requirement..

Answer (score 0):

If you need the mapper output to be saved as a file, you can simply run a mapper alone job. This can be done either by removing the reducer class or by setting the propery job.setNumReduceTasks(0).
If your requirement is to print the mapper output, you just do a System.out.println(key,value).

If your requirement is to print the reducer input, I mean the key, list[values]. You can do a System.out.println in the reduce method.

For printing all the intermediate values, you can do print statements in **Mapper** class, **Partitioner** class and **Reducer** class.

Comment: I don't want to print on the screen. I want to write this data on the HDFS out- put file(part-00000) that is by using output.collect();

Comment: Input file::
Dravid Banglore
Sachin Mumbai
Dhoni Ranchi
Dravid Jaipur
Dhoni Chennai
Sehwag Delhi
Gambhir Delhi
Gambhir Calcutta

I am expecting::
Dravid Banglore,Jaipur
Dhoni Ranchi,Chennai
Gambhir Delhi,Calcutta
Sachin Mumbai
Sehwag Delhi              reducer output.